# jQuery - extended menu

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover

I'd like to realize the following. I've got several small images and if the mouse is on one of the images, a `div` or some buttons should become visible. But if the mouse moves to another image, another `div` (buttons) should be displayed and the old `div` should be hidden. If no image is selected nothing should be displayed. Is there any function in the jQuery library to do something like that?

I tried to do this with a `mouseover` function and `toogle()`. But the problem is, when the mouse leaves the image, the recently displayed `div` is is hidden again. In addition, if I set the `div` to visible on `mouseover` it will still be displayed even if another image is selected.

```
<div id="Div1">This is div1</div>
<div id="Div2">This is div2</div>​
```

When the mouse goes over "div1", "div2" should be displayed until the mouse leaves "div1" or "div2". This means, ifthe mouse goes over "div2" (mouse left "div1"), "div2" should still be displayed.

Comment: Can you post your html here ?

Comment: Post a concise question and get a specific answer.   http://sscce.org/

Comment: Ok, I added some html and further explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want [jQuery hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).  It's difficult to provide an exact answer since your question contains no code but this fits what you've described.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myDiv").hover(
      function() {
        $("#otherDiv").show();
      }, 
      function() {
        $("#otherDiv").hide();
      }
    );
});
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XGXJz/1/)

**EDIT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#wrapper").hover(
      function() {
        $("#otherDiv").show();
      }, 
      function() {
        $("#otherDiv").hide();
      }
    );
});​
```

CSS:

```
#otherDiv {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="myDiv">hover me</div>
    <div id="otherDiv">stuff</div>
</div>​
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XGXJz/7/)

Comment: Thank u. But the problem is. When I move the mouse from "myDiv" to "otherDiv" will be hidden. This is the problem. The "otherDiv" should be still visible until the mouse leaves "otherDiv" or "myDiv".

Comment: @Chronnie, Just put it all in a wrapper.  See updated demo above.